# if in adress labels

Tags: tokens

can I somehow make an if-statement in the adress labels

What I want to do is a diffent label depending on the contact type. Basically something like this (not working)

```
if (contacttype = "organisation") {
   {contact.display_name} 
   {contact.street_address}
   {contact.postal_code} {contact.city}
   {contact.country}
}

if (contacttype = "individual) {
   {contact.display_name} > works
   {contact.street_address}
   {contact.postal_code} {contact.city}
   {contact.country}
}
```

The organisation tokens work but with the individual adress I have a problem because I somehow have to get the street of the organisation. I tried {contact.employer_id.street_address} but no sucess

thanks for any help
werner

Comment: Not suggesting it is the solution to your problem, but are you aware of the 'shared address' feature, ie you could potentially edit Jack to use a Shared Address of his workplace?

Answer (score 1):

So I haven't tried this but if it were going to work I think it would look like

```
{if '{contact.contact_type}' == "Organization")} 
   {contact.display_name} 
   {contact.address_primary.street_address}
   {contact.address_primary.postal_code} {contact.address_primary.city}
   {contact.address_primary.country_id:label}
{/if}


{if '{contact.contact_type}' == "Individual")} 
   {contact.display_name} > works
   {contact.employer_id.address_primary.street_address}
   {contact.employer_id.address_primary.postal_code} {contact.employer_id.address_primary.city}
   {contact.employer_id.address_primary.country_id:labe}
{/if}
```

Comment: Hmm - looks like we only exposed the display_name for the employer id https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/eb5c74e91286062409462250b1f140297fdcc79a/CRM/Contact/Tokens.php#L669